# How do I include multiple templates in php

Tags: php, templates

I am learning my way around php applying some *Separation of Concerns*. I am at localhost/admin/index.php.

I have my index.php as follows

```
...
$admin = new Admin();
if($_SESSION["user_privilege"]!=100) {
    header("Location: error.php");
    exit;
}

else 

include('views/admin_panel.php');
```

'admin_panel.php'

```
 !DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Admin Panel </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    /** Create an array of admin features with the key being the get url
        * and the value being the feature 
        */
        $tasks  = array('user_accounts'=> 'User account Management','products'   => 'Product management','categories' => 'Category Management','static_pages'=>'Page creation and deletion', 'customer_query'=> 'Answer Queries from users');

            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($tasks as $key => $val) {

                echo '<li><a href="index.php?'.$key.'">'.$val.'</a></li>';

                }
            echo '</ul>';

            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's simple stuff. Now, if I have a GET request to, say index.php?user_accounts, and I have that template at 'views/user_accounts.php', I've added the following lines to index.php

```
if ($admin->clickAction("user_accounts") == true)
            include('views/user_accounts.php');
#The functions are defined in the model
```

But, is this the right way to do it? I guess not, because the previously included admin_panel also appears with the user_accounts template which is not what I was hoping for.

Comment: Why not just use an if/else statement to include one or the other?

Comment: An even better option would be to use a router for routing certain actions. See http://altorouter.com/ or https://github.com/klein/klein.php for examples.

Comment: Is the worst way because you are consumming a lot of memmory of your page with innesary process. If I where in your place, we were'nt include anything and then, make a class with privates functions where you can identify your conditions and only includes the functions with your other code (includes)

Comment: Can you please elaborate @FernandoUrban